# How should we abbreviate the tag for 'Knights of pen and paper 2"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Well, as in the title. [knights-of-pen-and-paper-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-of-pen-and-paper-2) is too long, so I removed the `and-` ([knights-of-pen-paper-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-of-pen-paper-2)) so that it fits and is different from the original game: [knights-of-pen-and-paper](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-of-pen-and-paper). Also the difference between 1 and 2 is clear. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I own Knights of Pen and Paper +1, which of these tags would apply to any questions I might have? Ah, a new version! Well, this is excellent news

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the tag as written works well enough - it has enough of the terms in the title that it would still show up well in Google.

Answer (score 0):

We could try KoPP2, on the developer's twitter page that is how it is usually abbreviated. However Knights of Pen and Paper 2 pulls more relevant result on Google

Comment: We can make a tag synonym for it

Comment: You mean like Virtual Pen and Paper